# What is the callback and err in async.whilst used for?

Tags: javascript, node.js, while-loop, async.js

I'm trying to use async.whilst to regenerate a random number between 0 and the length of an array, until the length of the element on this index is larger than a specified length. I wanted to use async.whilst for this, but the syntax is not completely clear to me. I thought about doing the following:

```
var selectParagraph = function(paragraphs, callback){
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * paragraphs.length
    async.whilst(
        function(){ 
            return paragraphs[index].length < minParagraphLength; 
        },
        function(cb) {
            index = Math.floor(Math.random() * paragraphs.length);
        },
        function(err) {
            console.log(paragraphs[index]);
            callback(err, paragraphs[index]);
        }
    }
```

However,  this doesn't work. I suppose it is because I didn't use the cb for the second function anywhere, but I don't exactly know how I should use it. Do I just call cb() after changing the index? What exactly does the variable err contain?

Comment: Why aren't you just using a normal `while` loop here? It doesn't appear that you're making any asynchronous calls.

Comment: I have to perform a callback after the while loop finishes. Won't the callback happen before the normal while loop finishes? I will add the callback in my code example for clarity.

Comment: A `while` loop like this is synchronous (it doesn't depend on any asynchronous operations), so you can call your callback after it has finished.

Comment: @Eva: Why do you have to perform a callback? Your function does nothing async, so it shouldn't need to take a callback.

Comment: This while loop is performed in a function that is called in the main function, so I need to perform a callback containing the chosen index to the main function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Bergi has already noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29969813/710446), you are not doing anything asynchronous and do not need to use `whilst` at all. I'll further address your specific confusion about how `whilst` works, however.

The second argument to `whilst` is a function that may perform asynchronous operations. `whilst` has no way of knowing when the function is "done" with everything it needs to do. The callback parameter is a way to signal to `whilst` that this function has fully completed all its tasks, and `whilst` can proceed to the next iteration.

Suppose we want to make a series console message each one second apart. (This is a pretty contrived example, but I can't think of a natural example that's easier to explain.)

```
var i = 0;
async.whilst(
    function(){ return i < 5; },

    function(cb) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(i++);
            cb();
        }, 1000);
    },

    function(err) { console.err("we encountered an error", err); }
);
```

In this case, we call `setTimeout` and then `whilst` does not execute the next iteration until the `cb()` is called in the `setTimeout` resolution. If `whilst` ran the next iteration as soon as the function terminated, all the `setTimeout` calls would be queued up at the same time, rather than running on second after another. Instead, it waits until the function calls `cb()`.

Since you never call `cb()` in your code, `whilst` just assumes that the function has dispatched an async task that is taking a very long time. `whilst` will not run the next iteration until that first function call confirms that it is done by calling `cb()`.

A call to `cb()` with no arguments signals that the function completed its tasks with no problems. If the function finished with an error (couldn't read a file, couldn't access a network resource), then you can supply that error as an argument to `cb` (e.g. `cb(new Error("could not reach the server"));`) and the error will be supplied to the `whilst`'s third function argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do I just add the remaining commando's after the async.whilst, or do I add them in function(err) like with async.each etc.?

Comment: @Eva: yes. Everything that you want to execute asynchronously, after the `whilst` loop is done, needs to go into the callback.

Comment: I am using the same format but from the v3 this way of using the whilst has changed

Answer (score 4):

> I suppose it is because I didn't use the callback for the second function anywhere

Yes, exactly. `async.js` expects you to call back when you're done, and when you don't it will not continue with the next iteration.

> but I don't exactly know how I should use it

You shouldn't use it at all, since you are doing nothing asynchronous. Use a standard `do while` loop:

```
do {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * paragraphs.length); 
} while (paragraphs[index].length < minParagraphLength)
console.log(paragraphs[index]);

callback(null, paragraphs[index]); // not sure where you're getting `callback` from
```

Comment: Thanks, a normal do while loop indeed works, I thought this would not. The callback is necessary because this loop is included in a function, which I edited in the original question. Could you maybe explain what the cb and err in the async.whilst parameters exactly are? This way, I can use them when necessary.